# SEO with .htaccess not working on local WAMP server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I’m developing a frontend/backend application using PHP/MySQL. The project is almost done but I want to mask the variables displayed on the URL but something is not working on my WAMP local server.

`mod_rewrite` is active in Apache.

Below I provide us the information needed:

```
http://127.0.0.1/bookstoreSystem/index.php?page=home&language=en
```

I want to transform the URL above into:

```
http://127.0.0.1/bookstoreSystem/en/home/
```

I used the following code in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /^([^/]*)/^([^/]*)/\.php index.php?page=$1&language=$2
```

beyond this, when I run this code and tried to see the site, nothing changes or not working

What's the correct way to achieve this?

/*********/

The .htaccess is placed on this path:

```
c:/wamp/www/
```

and the project folder

```
c:/wamp/www/bookstoreSystem
```

Comment: Can you tell me what the first `^` accomplishes in `/^([^/]*)/`? Because that shouldn't be there.

Comment: It's true but I've tried a lot of sentences and the truth is the server is not change the url. Last time I used this: ^(.+)/(.+)/$ index.php?page=$1&language=$2

Comment: Yeah, but you should have tried `/^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/\.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a bit confusing:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /^([^/]*)/^([^/]*)/\.php index.php?page=$1&language=$2
```

What is that `\.php` supposed to be?

Try this instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule     ^([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$    index.php?page=$1&language=$2 [L]
```

Also, unclear about where in your system the `.htaccess` will be placed based on this URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1/bookstoreSystem/en/home/
```

So it might be best to shift the captured parameters over by one number; to `$2` and `$3` instead if `$1` and `$2`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule     ^([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$    index.php?page=$2&language=$3 [L]
```

**EDIT:** The original poster now says:

> The .htaccess is placed on this path:
>
> ```
> c:/wamp/www/
> ```
>
> and the project folder
>
> ```
> c:/wamp/www/bookstoreSystem
> ```

Two solutions. First, just take the `.htaccess` and place it in `c:/wamp/www/bookstoreSystem`.

Or keep the `.htaccess` in `c:/wamp/www/` and just use this reworked `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule     ^([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$    index.php?page=$2&language=$3 [L]
```

Note the three capture areas of `^([a-z0-9-_]+)`. That captures all three segments, but the rule then only uses `$2` & `$3`. Which means that `bookstoreSystem/` gets discarded, but `en/home/` is acted on.

Comment: I tested but the url is not changed. I still see this: http://127.0.0.1/bookstoreSystem/index.php?page=home&language=en

Comment: but if I want to see this: http://127.0.0.1/bookstoreSystem/en/home/ why APACHE did not convert the URL?

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /bookstoreSystem/en/home was not found on this server.

Comment: Just a last question, which should be the correct url to access?